# UrlHelper sometimes not returning the base url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a .NET Core 2.1 web api and am experiencing issues with the `UrlHelper`. I use the `Link` method to determine links from one resource to another. Most of the time it is working just fine, but sometimes the resulting string lacks the base url.

E.g.:

- Request 1: `http://localhost:1234/api/books?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10` OK
- Request 2: `http:///api/books?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10` not OK

And it goes back and forth between the correct and the wrong result, sometimes all of them are wrong, other times all of them are OK.

ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper, UrlHelper>(factory =>
        {
            var actionContext = factory.GetService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
            return new UrlHelper(actionContext);
        });
```

Example method for creating the links (pagination):

```
        public string CreateResourceUri(
        ResourceUriType type,
        string name,
        IUrlHelper urlHelper,
        object additionalValues = null)
    {
        dynamic values = CreateValues().Merge(additionalValues);

        switch (type)
        {
            case ResourceUriType.PreviousPage:
                values.pageNumber = values.pageNumber - 1;
                return urlHelper.Link(
                    name,
                    values);
            case ResourceUriType.NextPage:
                values.pageNumber = values.pageNumber + 1;
                return urlHelper.Link(
                    name,
                    values);
            default:
                return urlHelper.Link(
                    name,
                    values);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on what's going wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, try to use IUrlHelperFactory to create an instance UrlHelper rather than doing it directly.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: We implemented the IUrlHelperFactory suggestion which came at the cost of making the code less maintainable, but at least it is giving the correct urls.

Comment: Damn, I'm using that and still have this problem, but only when running in a container. Weird.